# Ajax return full page

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, django

Ajax return full page instead of return Value of Input. Ajax with Django didn't work properly well. It must be a one-page web app. I tried to make a template for Calc as a separate page but didn't work too.

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'', views.main, name = 'main'),
    url(r'calc/$', views.calc, name = 'calc')
]
```

**Views.py**

```
def main(request):
    return render(request, 'main/index.html',
context = {
    'some': some
    }
)

def calc(request):
    if request.GET:
        outputdata = request.GET('somedata')
        return HttpResponse(outputdata)
```

**index.html**

```
...
<div>
    <form action="{% url 'calc' %}" method="GET">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="someinput" value="somevalue">
    </form>
    <button type="submit" id="somebutton">Button</button>
</div>
...
```

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#somebutton').on('click', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'calc',
            data: {
                'somedata': $('#someinput').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Alert**

[image]

**Thanks to all who responded.**

Solution is use path instead of url.

```
path('', views.main, name = 'main'),
path('calc/', views.calc, name = 'calc')
```

And write outputdata = request.GET.get('somedata') instead of outputdata = request.GET('somedata').

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What happened?

Comment: @roganjosh _"Ajax return full page"_ instead of `request.GET('somedata')` only

Comment: Not at all clear what expected behavior is. Take a few minutes to help others help you by reading [ask]

Comment: AJAX calls usually don't return an entire HTML page as their result. Instead, the idea behind AJAX is to return _portions_ of a page (some data you are interested in). That data is then typically injected into the page using JavaScript.

Comment: @Andreas but is that desired behaviour or not? The OP goes one to say "it has to be a single page app". Why does the code take a request and immediately send it back? Surely this is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that your main URLpattern matches everything. So when you make the Ajax request, it is served by the view that returns a full page, not the one that returns a single value.

Make sure you use beginning and terminating anchors:

```
url(r'^$', views.main, name = 'main'),
url(r'^calc/$', views.calc, name = 'calc')
```

Or use the new path syntax:

```
path('', views.main, name = 'main'),
path('calc/', views.calc, name = 'calc')
```

Comment: That's maybe better. But if i wrote this in case of error                  
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(data) {
    alert('error');} Alert show an error.

Comment: Thanks. It's work if combine with another answer.

Answer (score 0):

You use return

```
HttpResponse(outputdata)
```

but you need to use

```
from django.http import JsonResponse 

return JsonResponse({"foo":"bar")
```

so import JsonResponse and change HttpResponse to JsonResponse

```
def calc(request):
    if request.GET:
        outputdata = request.GET('somedata')
        return JsonResponse({"outputdata":outputdata}, safe=False)
```

Comment: Same. No changes.

Comment: @SergeiPopov try outputdata = request.GET.get('somedata') or outputdata = request.GET[somedata']

Comment: nothing changes.

Comment: request.GET.get('somedata') helps me. Thanks